# match two unique chars with maximum repeat. How to extract this using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string `"aaabbcccjjjggggggkkkkkkkhhjj"`. I want to match `ggggggkkkkkkk` which are two unique letters with maximum repeat appearing together. How to extract this using regular expression in python?

Comment: Your problem is not clear. What do you want to match when they don't appear together? `k` repeats 7 times, while `g` only repeats 6 times, so do you want to match the longest repeated string and the second longest repeated string? Anyway, regex can only at most help you to extract repeated strings. You need to do the rest of the work with code.

Answer (score 1):

```
x="aaabbcccjjjggggggkkkkkkkhhjj"
import re
print max(re.findall(r"((.)\2+(.)\3+)",x),key=lambda k:len(k[0]))[0]
```

You can find all such possible combinations using `re.findall` and then take out the `max` based on the length.

Output:`ggggggkkkkkkk`